# How do we clear previous page data on SelectedIndexChanged Event..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, reportviewer

I have aspx page.having an issue is that if we select first time option from drop down value gets appears on the page.but when we select second time option from drop down still previous data getting appears. how do i clear all the previous data after drop-down SelectedIndexChanged Event..?

Comment: please edit your question and put it your code.

Comment: have you made first option as  default display option for the dropdown?

Comment: No.i have not set any default display option.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not provided the code when i'm writing this answer. In Asp.net u can achieve this by using jquery. I'm using `club` dropdown list with ID `clubs` as an example. This event will bind to the list and will keep on updating `selected` variable when the selectedIndex change. Then you can simply pass the `selected` variable value to lets say a `span` element with id `spanClub`

```
$(document).ready(() => {
$('#Clubs').change(() => {
   let selected = $('#Clubs :selected').text();
   $('#spanClub').text(selected);
});
});
```

Comment: is there need to be disabled any View state related property...?

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. Please see my problem statement. i have a drop down with Autopostback true property. after page load consider if we select "state" option then state data gets display on grid view from the database. but next time when we select another option e.g "country" but country data is not present in database. but still for the country option previous "state" data is display on grid view which we were first time select after page .just want to clear all the previous data on the same page on selectedIndexChanged Event.